# Should functions be inside jQuery's extend, or outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I am writing my first jQuery plugin, and I'm not entirely sure what should be *inside* the extension declaration and what shouldn't.

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    var somevar = this;
    someFunc(somevar);
};
function someFunc() {/*doSomethin'*/};
```

OR

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    var somevar = this;
    someFunc(somevar);
    function someFunc() {/*doSomethin'*/};
};
```

Comment: obviously the issue with the first one is that if you use it on a new project you will need to make sure that you have already defined `someFunc()`, which means making it as a plugin isn't really going to achieve much. surely?

Comment: @JoshStevenson I assumed that the whole thing would go in a single file, e.g. `myplugin.jquery.js` in which case it wouldn't matter, right?

Comment: As a side note, your plugin should return the matched set of elements to keep jQuery chaining

Comment: @A.Wolff Could you elaborate? Or refer me to useful documentation? As I'm still learning, all didactic material is welcome.

Comment: @BramVanroy https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'd use the first option because:
>
> It doesn't have any negative side effects.

That's where you are wrong. If you are working with different libraries you risk overwriting someone elses someFunc(), possibly breaking whatever they were trying to do for you.  A safer way would be to wrap a closure around your code.

```
(function(){

$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    var somevar = this;
    someFunc(somevar);
};

function someFunc() {/*doSomethin'*/};

/* Do whatever other things you need someFunc/myplugin for */

})();
```

This way your someFunc is shielded from the global namespace.

Alternatively what you might be looking to do is to expose the method of the object to the outside world. Take following example:

```
$.fn.dog = function () {

     this.bark = function() {alert("Woof");};

     return this;
};

var $max = new $('#myDogMax').dog();
$max.bark();
```

This keeps the function within the context of your object but makes it possible to access it cleanly from the outside. Although this usually means that the method is somehow related to the object.  It would make little sense to write a bark() function globally, as it are usually dogs that tend do it and not browser windows.

Answer (score 5):

In your first method, you end up polluting the global scope adding `someFunc()`. The second method doesn't.

However, that doesn't automatically mean the second method is better. If you enclose the first method in a closure, it basically ends up being the exact same thing, and comes down to personal preference.
Here, it might even be better to use the first method (in a closure), so that if you have multiple jQuery extensions in a single JS file, they can share this base function.

Comment: If the OP created this plugin with the function in a personal lib he could check if it existed before redefining it within the plugin. This way it would use the global scope function when the plugin can and just create it within the plugin if it can't

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand If function is specific to plugin method, it should be defined inside plugin, otherwise on any outter scope, depending use case

Comment: Just to be sure, by *closure* you mean something like a self-invoking function, right?